# find inner value of a table cell of datatable using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable, cell, html-table

I've the following data table defined.

Problem - after the datatable is drawn, when i retrieve value from slider jquery input, I recieve span and whole text instead of value. How do i retrieve just the value of sliderinput?

```
 <table class="zebra" cellpadding ="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" id="subscriptionsTable" width="100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                User  
            </th>
            <th>
                Name Full
            </th>
            <th>
                Sub Frequency
            </th>
            <th>
                Price
            </th>
            <th>
                Rep
            </th>
            <th>
                Sales
            </th>
            <th>
                Points
            </th>
            <th>
                Save
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Below are the values on the screen,

```
    <td class="sorting_1">60728</td>
    <td>Les</td>
    <td>Y</td>
    <td>799</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td>
    <span class="ui-spinner ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">
    <input id="pointSlider" class="ui-spinner-input" type="number" step="1" min="0" aria-valuemin="0" autocomplete="off" role="spinbutton" style="border-width: 1px; border-color: rgb(206, 206, 206);" aria-valuenow="4">
    <a class="ui-spinner-button ui-spinner-up ui-corner-tr ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-button-text-only" tabindex="-1" role="button" aria-disabled="false">
    <a class="ui-spinner-button ui-spinner-down ui-corner-br ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-button-text-only" tabindex="-1" role="button" aria-disabled="false">
    </span>
    </td>
td>
<img class="save" width="20px" title="Save this record" src="https://localhost:8443/project/images/Green_Check.png">
</td>
```

When I select any row, I'm able to capture row elements using the following jQuery select.

```
$(this).closest('tr').find('td').eq(0).html();
```

How do I select 6th element? I've a slider jquery with ID=pointSlider and could not find the value.

Help appreciated, newbie at jQuery.

Comment: You want 6th row or 6th column in the currently selected row?

Comment: @JawwadAlam 6th column value currently selected.

Comment: Create a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) to clearly explain your question.

Comment: If your code above `$(this).closest('tr').find('td').eq(0).html();` is giving the you the content of first cell of currently selected row, you can modify that to get 6th cell content like this  `$(this).closest('tr').find('td:nth-child(6)').html();`

Comment: @JawwadAlam Its a bit hard to create and replicate on jsfiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/abhilashm86/dwf7e8e1/

Comment: See my [comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25191737/find-inner-value-of-a-table-cell-of-datatable-using-jquery?noredirect=1#comment39230685_25191737) above

Comment: @JawwadAlam it returns just "".

Comment: @JawwadAlam this worked - $(this).closest('tr').find('#pointSlider').val(); tested enough, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

This select works. Input is wrapped around a span contained in a table cell.
$(this).closest('tr').find('#pointSlider').val();